# DropDown list with text Field using Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to develop a text field drop down list in Struts2.
This means a user can type the word and field will show all matching list. Its easy to use  because `<S:select list="abd"></s:list>` display all items. If a list is big then  the user will have problem to select an item from the list so its better to provide a text field with the drop down, the a user can select any item via typing a word or selecting from the drop down.

Please help me on this.
Code should be in jsp file and action bean.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You should show us what code you have tried and explain what problems you had with it. This is not a coding service, and people do not provide code in response to specifications. Please tell us more. The the [edit] button to add to your question.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 my translator says the Chinese part of your nick means "Tom Ryan"... ? :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios. Yes - it's my name in Mandarin.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 But Brian != Ryan and Tompsett != Tom :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Let's continue in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12811/chinese-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve my problem .
for a drop down list in Struts 2

```
<s:select list="we" name=" my-List "></s:select>
now just use
<sj:auto-completer list="we" name="my-List"></ sj:autocompleter>
```